# Pandas insert whitespace after reading DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When i read a file with `pd.read_fwf` i define exactly the field widths:

```
df = pd.read_fwf("file", widths=[8,6,5])
```

Plotting the dataframe `print(df)`, an extra whitespace appears between the columns:

original data f.e.:

```
    col1  col2 col3 
20120101   -11   23
20120101     4   11 
20120101     9   92
```

after read into DataFrame:

```
    col1   col2  col3 
20120101    -11    23
20120101      4    11 
20120101      9    92
```

Can I prevent that? The original width of the columns of the input file must be preserved. 
I get in trouble when I want to save the dataframe with numpy:

```
np.savetxt('file.txt', df.values, fmt='%8s %5s %4s')
```

As you can see I have to subtract the extra space in the format parameter to preserve the original state. But can that be the solution?

Comment: could you clarify on what you mean by "whitespace appears between the columns" / give an example? this could just be a matter of displaying things for better readability.

Comment: i have added an example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not related to `pandas` but the format string you pass to `np.savetxt`. if you add whitespaces there, they will propagate to the format.
remove them to get the desired output:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = 'D:/fwf.txt' # file holding the text from the example
df = pd.read_fwf(file, widths=[8,6,5])
np.savetxt('D:/fwf_out.txt', df.values, fmt='%8s%6s%5s')
```

now, `fwf_out.txt` will hold text formatted exactly as specified, just the column headers removed.

---

**edit:** to also get the column header with the specified format, you could e.g. do

```py
WIDTHS = [8, 6, 5]
df = pd.read_fwf(file, widths=WIDTHS)

# determine the formats based on WIDTH:
col_fmts = [f'%{w}s' for w in WIDTHS] # ['%8s', '%6s', '%5s']

header = ''.join(f % c for f, c in zip(col_fmts, df.columns))
np.savetxt('D:/fwf_out.txt', df.values, header=header, fmt=''.join(col_fmts), comments='')
```

Comment: @mcatis: added an option, a bit complicated maybe, I'll see if I can come up with something simpler ;-)